# httpd VirtualHost overwrite another VirtualHost

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a problem whereby my VirtualHost is overriding another VirtualHost on the same domain.

httpd.conf

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

example.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example/chain.cer
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

get.example.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/get.example/
        ServerName get.example.com
        ServerAlias get.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

When I created `get.example.conf` and when I accessed `example.com`, it is showing the content of `get.example.com`

Does anyone knows what is going wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Because, you don't have any configuration for example.com, only for www.example.com. Try adding ServerName example.com and ServerAlias www.example.com. It's all.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I need to include the non-www for the VirtualHost as well. It works if I entered `www.example.com` but not `example.com`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need add a ServerAlias with www

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set up de ServerAlias.
In your example, it should be enough to do as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that **ServerName** doesn't has *www.*, so that it's gonna match **http://example.com**, while with the **ServerAlias** it's gonna match **http://www.example.com**

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the order of `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` to your get.example.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName get.example.com
        ServerAlias get.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/get.example/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Order no matters is a single file for settings